# Firefox duplicate images scaling poorly

Tags: html, image, firefox, rendering, scaling

I have noticed a quirk in Firefox v34's (and possibly other versions) rendering of scaled images. As far as I have been able to determine, this quirk happens only when the same image is displayed multiple times on a page, and when at least one of them is scaled.

In this case, the image quality suffers considerably when compared to the rendering of a single image.

You can see this quirk by running the following code snippet. Initially, both images are rendered quite poorly. But, if you click on one of them, it will become hidden, and the quality of the other image will improve greatly.

Anybody know what is causing this behavior, and if there is a known workaround?

```css
img {
  width: 125px;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.tau.ac.il/~tsirel/dump/Static/knowino.org/w/images/thumb/5/50/Periodic_table.PNG/800px-Periodic_table.PNG" onclick="this.style.display='none';"/>
<img src="http://www.tau.ac.il/~tsirel/dump/Static/knowino.org/w/images/thumb/5/50/Periodic_table.PNG/800px-Periodic_table.PNG" onclick="this.style.display='none';"/>
```